# EcmaScript 6 module requiring, how does it work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, aurelia, commonjs

So I know how to require and export modules in ES6. But for frameworks like [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/), the docs say that you require `aurelia` like so:

```
import {LogManager} from 'aurelia-framework';
```

Do I have to place a JS file named `aurelia-framework` in the folder where the JS file I'm executing it from resides, or does the `import` function work similiar to the `require` function in NodeJS/CommonJS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this article](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html) ES6 modules spec only deals with loading modules that are present in the file path. Downloading these files (via NPM or by other means) is outside of scope of [ECMAScript 6 modules spec](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-imports). Nothing is said in the spec about supporting npm package includes (traversing the directory structure down to the `/`, one directory at a time, looking for a `package.json` file and then searching within the `node_modules` directory where `package.json` file is found). So while the `import` syntax is similar to commonJS style, the whole magic of looking for modules in the `node_modules` directory is not included.

So for your example to work, `aurelia-framework` must be a javascript file somewhere in your file system and it should contain an `exports` statement.

```
import {LogManager} from 'aurelia-framework'; // ./aurelia-framework.js
import {LogManager} from '../libs/aurelia-framework'; // ../libs/aurelia-framework.js
```

Answer (score 0):

with [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io), you can install dependent libraries [using jspm](http://jspm.io).  you can see [an example of that here](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation#running-the-app).  jspm will get the packages for you and bring them into subfolders in your project.  jspm uses an index (stored in config.js) to know where to locate the files (similar to how requirejs, but works for amd, commonjs, and es6 modules).

there is also [an example](https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript#just-use-it---visual-studio-using-requirejs-amd-module-loader) of using the aurelia libraries with requirejs amd loader.  this example uses a bundle of aurelia libraries generated by r.js [as shown here](https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript#bundling)